# jQuery.validate event of before validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have following code

```
$("#Form").validate({

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.addClass('errorField');
        element.after(error);
    },
    rules: {
        ...
    }
});
```

The `errorPlacement` function is setting a css `class` `errorField` to the element when it fails the described rules and every time before validation I want to remove this class `errorField`.

```
element.removeClass('errorField');
```

So my question, **is there any event in jquery.validate that fires before the validation took place?**

so if that `element` is hosting this class `errorField`, the above code will remove the class from this element and will re-validate the field and may apply this class again if the field fails the rules again.

This may also done in any event that fires **after the validation** so if the element passes the rule I will remove the class `errorField`.

**Note:** `errorField` is a css class that will highlight the field to notify the user about the error

Comment: Can you show a more complete code example as well as explain what you want in more detail?  You start out asking about how to remove a class and then you end up talking about form events that are not represented by your code.  It seems very disconnected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by *"before validation"*.  How is the plugin supposed to know what to do *before* something happens?

**Quote OP:**

> *"The validation triggers at both events `form.submit` and `form.change`, It works fine with `form.submit`, but i didn't work for `form.change`"*

*"It works fine..."*  ~ What works fine?  You have not shown any code whatsoever for what you're trying to describe here.  The plugin *will* trigger validation with its built in events like `onkeyup` and `onfocusout`.  (The form changes on every key up).

I think the problem *might* be in your interpretation of the `errorPlacement` callback function's intended purpose.  It's only purpose is for layout... for *one-time **placement*** of the error message object within your page.  Once placed, it's not *re*-placed... it's toggled.

I think you may want to use `highlight` and `unhighlight` instead.  These two callbacks will fire every time an element is validated.  In other words, these are the two callbacks that will toggle messages as they're validated.

However, I'm not sure you even need to go this far.  It looks like you simply want to toggle a class called `.errorField`.  If that's the case, just add this class to the default error classes with the `errorClass` option and it will automatically toggle as needed.

```
$("#Form").validate({
    errorClass: 'error errorField', // specify classes to toggle on error (default: error)
    validClass: 'valid', // specify classes to toggle on validity (default: valid)
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        // element.addClass('errorField'); // <-- remove this line
        element.after(error);
    },
    rules: {
        ...
    }
});
```

[See all options & callback functions here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope it is clearly understandable now, Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can add this on submit event of form or on click of a submit button:

```
$('.errorField').removeClass('errorField');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this post but this is the solution I usually use:

You can create a new validation method or edit any of the built-in validation methods, like this:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

```
$.validator.addMethod("mymethod", function(){
    doSomethingBeforeCheck();
    return ruleValidator();
});
```

With this, u can do whatever you want before your rules are checked, in order to perform any action before validation.

Comment: Can you tell me what is "ruleValidator" ? I cannot find it and though it seems your suggestion does not work.